# Bash: Unable to enter into if even the condition is true

Tags: mysql, wordpress, bash, backup

I am building a script which will backup a WordPress database.
I have created the function need for the MySQL dump:

```
function db_backup {
    read -r -p "Dump the database? [Y/n]: " response
    if [[ $response =~ ^([yY][eE][sS] || [yY])$ ]]
    then
        mysqldump -h $1 -u $2 -p$3 $4 > $4.sql

        if [[ $? == 0 ]]
        then
            printf "Database %s dumped successfuly in %s.sql\n" ${db_name} ${db_name}
            return 0
        else
            printf "Database backup %bfailed%b\n" ${red} ${reset}
            return 1
        fi  
    else
        return 1
    fi  
}
```

When Y or Yes/yEs/yeS/YES/yes is hitter - it does not enter in the if true block, and no dump is created :( The database details are correct and the dump goes on hand, but I am not able to enter in the IF condition.

Comment: Use quotes around the regexp, eg : `[[ $response =~ "^([yY][eE][sS] || [yY])$" ]]`

Comment: You regex will match (case-insensitive—quotes added for formatting purposes) `"yes "` (with a trailing space) or `" y"` (with a leading space) or the empty string `""`… is that what you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using a `case` statement:

```
db_backup()
{
    read -r -p "Dump the database? [Y/n]: " response

    case "$response" in
    y|Y|yes|Yes|YES)
        mysqldump -h $1 -u $2 -p$3 $4 > $4.sql

        if [[ $? == 0 ]]
        then
             printf "Database %s dumpedy in %s.sql\n" ${db_name} ${db_name}
             return 0
        else
             printf "Database backup %bfailed%b\n" ${red} ${reset}
             return 1
        fi
        ;;
    esac
    return 1

}
```

Comment: `shopt -s nocasematch` may also be of use here.

Comment: Your solution has done the job! Thanks to the others who attended my question too!

Answer (score 3):

Your regex matches (case-insensitive—quotes added for formatting purposes) `"yes "` (with a trailing space) or `" y"` (with a leading space) or the empty string `""`<sup>1</sup>.

Write this instead:

```
if [[ $response =~ ^([yY][eE][sS]|[yY])$ ]]
```

or even better

```
if [[ $response =~ ^[yY]([eE][sS])?$ ]]
```

You can also use globs:

```
if [[ $response = [yY]?([eE][sS]) ]]
```

(with Bash<4.1 you need `shopt -s extglob`). You can also convert `response` to lower case:

```
if [[ ${response,,} = y?(es) ]]
```

(the `${var,,}` parameter expansion appeared in Bash 4.0).

---

<sup>1</sup> and the funny thing is that `read` (with the default `IFS`) strips leading and trailing spaces… so it's impossible to have a match with a non-empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Why not transform the response to all caps first, then compare to Y or YES, for example, do:

`if [[ ${response^^} =~ ^(Y|YES)$ ]]; then ... fi`

This has the advantage that you don't need to think about the possible combinations of upper/lower case, they are all detected.  Also, instead of:

`if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then ... fi`

You can just do:

`if [[ $? ]]; then ... fi`

For truth tests, the result of `[[ 0 ]]` is true, whereas the result of `(( 0 ))` is false.

Consider some simplifications, for readability, such as

```
function db_backup {
    read -r -p "Dump the database? [Y/n]: " response
    if [[ ${response^^} =~ ^(Y|YES)$ ]]
    then
        if mysqldump -h $1 -u $2 -p$3 $4 > $4.sql
        then
            printf "Database %s dumped successfuly in %s.sql\n" ${db_name} ${db_name}
            return 0
        else
            printf "Database backup %bfailed%b\n" ${red} ${reset}
            return 1
        fi  
    else
        return 1
    fi  
}
```

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf : regex anchored, as advised, thanks.